# Change Parse Push Notification Current Channel In App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I have working code add to current user channel with parse sdk
But i want to change current Channel in app example  ( in Viewcontroller.m )

My codes here

Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    sleep(2);

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"
                  clientKey:@"sdfsdfsdfsdf"];

    // Register for Push Notitications
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}




- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];




    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

My view controller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"Second"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}
```

But don't change current user channel Frist to Second.
Im trying everything but don't change i need help. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try unsubscribing the user to the old channel and then subscribing it to the new one?

This is my code for subscribing and unsubscribing to a channel and it works fine:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"type1user" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

and for unsubscribing and subscribing to the sencond channel:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation removeObject:@"type1user" forKey:@"channels"];
//subcribing to the second channel
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"type2user" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Comment: THANKS DUDE DELETED SOME CODES AND WORKING NOW

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Glad to help :)